# wchar_t Bit Manipulation On Strings

Tags: c++, c, string, unicode, encode

Trying to write a function to dynamically encode and decode text. However when I tried to convert from Multibyte to Widechar I ran into some issues. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
BOOL decode_comp     = TRUE;
wchar_t decode_key[] = L"abc123";
wchar_t myMessage[]  = L"\x18\x35\x3C\x3C\x3F\x70\x07\x3F\x22\x3C\x34\x71\x00"; // Hello World

wchar_t *Decode(wchar_t *s)
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    wchar_t *string;

    string = (wchar_t *)malloc((wcslen(s) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));

    wcscpy(string, s);

    for (i = 0; i < wcslen(string); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sizeof(decode_key); j++)
            string[i] ^= decode_key[j];

        if (decode_comp)
            string[i] = ~string[i];
    }

    return string;
}
```

Comment: What does this return: `sizeof(decode_key);` ?

Comment: Could you be so kind as to explain what exactly happens which differs from you expectations? (And what does this have to do with multibyte strings?)

Comment: Also, pick a language, C or C++.  If doing this with C++, usage of two algorithm functions (`transform`, `for_each`) is all that's required.

Answer (score 2):

```
        for (j = 0; j < sizeof(decode_key); j++)
```

Here is the mistake: `sizeof()` always returns the size in bytes (number of `char`s), which is twice the number of characters in `decode_key`, as long as `wchar_t` has a size of 2 bytes. By the way, more correct syntax for this case is `(sizeof decodekey)`.

*Noteworthy comment from Weather Vane:* `sizeof(decode_key)` also includes the terminator, which you normally do not want to count.

```
wchar_t myMessage[]  = L"\x18\x35\x3C\x3C\x3F\x70\x07\x3F\x22\x3C\x34\x71\x00";
```

You do not need that `'\x00'` at the end of a string literal.

```
for (i = 0; i < wcslen(string); i++)
```

Be aware that the compiler may *not* move `wcslen()` evaluation out of loop body, and therefore it will be run on each iteration.

Comment: @MicroVirus Please elaborate. You may of course argue that a static array is a type by itself and therefore is suitable for `sizeof(type)` form, but `(sizeof expression)` states your intentions better anyway.

Comment: What I mean is that I do not agree with you that `(sizeof decodeKey)` is more correct than `sizeof(decodeKey)`. Otherwise, good answer, though you might want to also include @WeatherVane's comment into your answer to make it 'complete'.

Comment: `myMessage[]` will have *two* terminators (explicit and implicit) and both will be ignored by `wcslen()`. But using `sizeof` on `decode_key[]` will include the implicit terminator, which is *not* part of the decoding key.

Comment: @Anton: It is `sizeof expression` in either case.  `expression` can itself contain parentheses... but here they are completely redundant.  `; j < sizeof decode_key ;` would be perfectly fine, no parentheses at all are needed here.

Comment: @BenVoigt Although `sizeof(expr)` is the same as `(sizeof (expr))`, which is equal to just `(sizeof expr)`, I find it misleading to use an incorrectly looking form instead of proper one, even if it compiles just fine. In reverse, you cannot use `(sizeof type)` instead of `sizeof(type)`, as it will not compile at all. Their distinction is even clearer when attempting to use `(sizeof expr)` with a compiler not aware of C++11 improvements, because that would not work on a non-static member field. So it is good to remember the difference and explicitly state your intent in the code.